# Объединение нескольких дисков в Raid 0

Tags: linux, centos7

Всем привет, перечитав интернет не особо понял как объединить дополнительные диски к существующим.

2 диска по 1 ТБ ssd
Будет добавлено ещё 2 диска по 1 ТБ ssd.
=> В итоге 4 диска.

Как добавить 2 доп.диска к корню системы?

Os: Linux Centos 7

Comment: Ты хочешь сделать один здоровенный 4тб диск? Или задублировать текущюю конфигурацию?

Comment: Один большой диск

Comment: Ну а `mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sde` не пашет разве?

Comment: Я вообще не понял как это сделать)

Comment: Тогда лучше подними внутри virtualbox похожую конфигурацию по ковырни там. Иначе рискуешь потерять всё.